# How to update an old vba code to work on excel?

Tags: excel, vba

I have this code from an old book that does not work in my `Excel`. It is supposed to calculate the slope and intercept of a Deming regression from a range of numbers, x and y

```
Function Deming(XValues, YValues)
Dim MeanX(), MeanY()
Ncells = XValues.Count
ReDim MeanX(Ncells / 2), MeanY(Ncells / 2)

For x = 2 To Ncells Step 2
    MeanX(x / 2) = (XValues(x - 1) + XValues(x)) / 2
    MeanY(x / 2) = (YValues(x - 1) + YValues(x)) / 2
    SumX = SumX + MeanX(x / 2): SumY = SumY + MeanY(x / 2)
    SumX2 = SumX2 + (MeanX(x / 2)) ^ 2
    SumY2 = SumY2 + (MeanY(x / 2)) ^ 2
    SumXY = SumXY + MeanX(x / 2) * MeanY(x / 2)
    SumDeltaX2 = SumDeltaX2 + (XValues(x - 1) - XValues(x)) ^ 2
    SumDeltaY2 = SumDeltaY2 + (YValues(x - 1) - YValues(x)) ^ 2
Next

XBar = SumX / N: YBar = SumY / N
Sx2 = (N * SumX2 - SumX ^ 2) / (N * (N - 1))
Sy2 = (N * SumY2 - SumY ^ 2) / (N * (N - 1))
Sdx2 = SumDeltaX2 / (2 * N)
Sdy2 = SumDeltaY2 / (2 * N)
rPearson = (N * SumXY - SumX * SumY) / Sqr((N * SumX2 - SumX ^ 2) * (N * 
SumY2 - SumY ^ 2))


lambda = Sdx2 / Sdy2
U = (Sy2 - Sx2 / lambda) / (2 * rPearson * Sqr(Sx2) * Sqr(Sy2))
Slope = U + Sqr(U ^ 2 + 1 / lambda)
Intercept = YBar - Slope * XBar

Deming = Array(Slope, Intercept)
End Function
```

Does this have a bad syntax or not?

Comment: Do you get an error of some sort? On which line?

Comment: Perhaps you should try to run it first and ask questions later?

Comment: If the syntax is wrong, the program will not run. If it runs and returns the wrong answer, the syntax is right -- the computer can understand and execute the program -- but the program is answering the wrong question. If the computer attempts to run it, and it stops in the middle with an error, the computer understood the instructions and tried to carry them out, but failed.

Comment: That awkward moment, when you find the book and you see that this code took 3 years to be written... And it still does not work... https://books.google.de/books?id=1zoraGjXZSQC&pg=PA582&lpg=PA582&dq=Function+Deming(XValues,+YValues)+Dim+MeanX(),+MeanY()+Ncells+%3D+XValues.Count&source=bl&ots=k6MMhXREcM&sig=ACfU3U1OIkyBSeSS1nJQqOq6dx_tzT2G4A&hl=en&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwin1-WtjbDkAhWDIlAKHdZ5Ar0Q6AEwAHoECAkQAQ#v=onepage&q=Function%20Deming(XValues%2C%20YValues)%20Dim%20MeanX()%2C%20MeanY()%20Ncells%20%3D%20XValues.Count&f=false

Answer (score 2):

First this is not **old code**, this is simply **bad code**.

Anything in VBA, which does not compile, when someone writes `Option Explicit` on the top of the Module/Worksheet is a bad syntax. This is a rule of a thumb. And in the case of the code, if this one is pasted to the editor the following line is red:

```
rPearson = (N * SumXY - SumX * SumY) / Sqr((N * SumX2 - SumX ^ 2) * (N * 
SumY2 - SumY ^ 2))
```

This is because it should be in 1 line, and not in 2.

So, concerning the question - how to update it - as a first step, make sure the code compiles with `Option Explicit` on top ([Option Explicit statement](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/language/reference/user-interface-help/option-explicit-statement)). So, write `Option Explicit` and then go to Debug>Compile on the VBEditor's ribbon. VBeditor will highlight the problem. The first one is that `Ncell` is not defined:

[image]

Then find a way to define it, e.g. write `Dim Ncells as Variant` or as anything else you may consider useful on the top of the highligted line. It could be that just declaring a variable is not enough, as there is a calculation `XBar = SumX / N` in the code. There, `N` should be declared and assigned to a value. If it is only declared, it will be `0`, and then a division by 0 will be an error. Thus, probably something like this should be written, depending on the logic: `Dim N as Double: N = 1`

Comment: I would also recommend to use proper syntax for the function like `Function Deming(ByRef XValues as range, ByRef YValues as range)  as Variant`. And maybe it is also a good excercise to re-write the code in order to understand what it is doing. It might be possibe to remove the loop. But to be honest I'd leave that to the OP.